# Apply function on Tensor with unknown rank (Mean reciprocal rank)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'd like create a new evaluation metric to my model (Mean reciprocal rank).
Assume I have:

- `logits` tensor of shape `(None, n_class)` and
- `y_target` tensor of shape `(None, )` containing `int` values from `0` to `n_class-1`.
- `None` would be the batch size.

I'd like my output to be a tensor of shape `(None, )`, with the reciprocal ranks of the corresponding `y_target`. 
First I'd need to rank the elements in `logits`, then get the rank of the element in index `y_target`, then lastly, get its reciprocal (or the reciprocal of x+1, depending on the ranking procedure).

A simple example (for a single observation):
If my `y_target=1` and `logits=[0.5, -2.0, 1.1, 3.5]`,
then the ranking is `logits_rank=[3, 4, 2, 1]`
and the reciprocal would be `1.0 / logits_rank[y_target] = 0.25`.

The challenge here is to apply a function across an axis, since the rank is unknown (at the graph level). 
I've managed to get some results using `tf.nn.top_k(logits, k=n_class, sorted=True).indices`, but only within a `session.run(sess, feed_dict)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Solved!

```
 def tf_get_rank_order(input, reciprocal):
    """
    Returns a tensor of the rank of the input tensor's elements.
    rank(highest element) = 1.
    """
    assert isinstance(reciprocal, bool), 'reciprocal has to be bool'
    size = tf.size(input)
    indices_of_ranks = tf.nn.top_k(-input, k=size)[1]
    indices_of_ranks = size - tf.nn.top_k(-indices_of_ranks, k=size)[1]
    if reciprocal:
        indices_of_ranks = tf.cast(indices_of_ranks, tf.float32)
        indices_of_ranks = tf.map_fn(
            lambda x: tf.reciprocal(x), indices_of_ranks, 
            dtype=tf.float32)
        return indices_of_ranks
    else:
        return indices_of_ranks


def get_reciprocal_rank(logits, targets, reciprocal=True):
    """
    Returns a tensor containing the (reciprocal) ranks
    of the logits tensor (wrt the targets tensor).
    The targets tensor should be a 'one hot' vector 
    (otherwise apply one_hot on targets, such that index_mask is a one_hot).
    """
    function_to_map = lambda x: tf_get_rank_order(x, reciprocal=reciprocal)
    ordered_array_dtype = tf.float32 if reciprocal is not None else tf.int32
    ordered_array = tf.map_fn(function_to_map, logits, 
                              dtype=ordered_array_dtype)

    size = int(logits.shape[1])
    index_mask = tf.reshape(
            targets, [-1,size])
    if reciprocal:
        index_mask = tf.cast(index_mask, tf.float32)

    return tf.reduce_sum(ordered_array * index_mask,1)

# use:
recip_rank = tf.reduce_mean(
                 get_reciprocal_rank(logits[-1], 
                                     y_, 
                                     True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how MRR is implemented in tensorflow_ranking package: https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/python/metrics.py

Diving into the wrapper, they actually call the sorting function in `tensorflow.python.ops.gen_nn_ops.top_kv2`, which generated from C++ code to make things faster.

You can certainly write some `O(n)` algorithms without sorting by counting the number of smaller index for each instance. By it may not be as fast as the C++ code. You can get `logits` out and calculate with following codes.

```
def rev_rank(id: int, logit: list):
    return 1.0 / sum([logit[id] <= i for i in logit])

rev_rank_sum = sum(map(rev_rank, y_target, logits))
```